# How to increment a published var when accessed

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to setup some kind of global counter in my app. 
What the best way of doing this?

I have the following code that works but it's damn ugly, I'd like to increment when the var is accessed so I don't have to call the function.

I tried to use get and set but it's not possible with property wrappers.

```
class GlobalDisplayInfo: ObservableObject {

    @Published var nextAvailableInt : Int = 0

    func getNextAvailableInt() -> Int {
        nextAvailableInt += 1
        return self.nextAvailableInt
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not sure what you mean, too. Do you have to vars and do you want to increment var1 if var2 is accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is not possible as it is against how `Published` works.

Let's say you access the published var in two places:

When the first one accesses the var, it would increment the var which would require the second place where it uses this var to refresh (access to this var again) which would require the var to increment again which would require the other place which uses this var to access and it just goes on - I think you got the point.

Your problem basically sounds rather like a design problem and I suggest you review it. Also, I think it'd be better if you just tell us what you want to achieve (without using any coding language, just a plain explanation of what you want) then an answer might come up.

Comment: Experimenting further and you're absolutely right. Not to mention that you don't really control how many time the published var will get called.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear the usage, but looks like you need the following

```
class GlobalDisplayInfo: ObservableObject {

    private var _nextAvailableInt = 0
    var nextAvailableInt : Int {
        _nextAvailableInt += 1
        return _nextAvailableInt
    }
}
```